# How to say "doctor-patient confidentiality" more casually in French?

Tags: expressions, registre-familier

In my line of work, we use the term "doctor-patient confidentiality" all the time, but I'm looking for a more relaxed way to express the same idea in a casual conversation with my colleagues, for instance.

I said the following the other day, but I'm not sure it worked as well as I'd hoped:

> Ça, j’en discuterai avec elle. ***Dans les limites du secret médical***, en tout cas. Tu n'y verras pas d’inconvénient ?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People working in a medical field may have other terms. As a profane, the only term that comes to my mind is *secret médical*.

Comment: That's pretty much it. Sometimes you hear the more general "secret professionnel", though.